# How to take power of negative exponent in XSLT

Tags: xml, math, xslt

I am trying to take the negative power of a number but it is giving me an exception error. The expression works with a positive power but it does not work with a negative power.

What I tried (XSLT):

```
<xsl:value-of select="math:power(7,-2)"/>
```

What I expected (XML): `.07`

What I actually got (XML):

> Exception thrown by extension function

Comment: With Saxon, `math:pow(7, -2)` https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/functions/math/pow.html works and returns `0.02040816326530612`. What XSLT processor are you using, and what's the extension namespace?

Comment: If your processor does not support the `math:power` extension function (or supports it only for positive exponents, however unlikely it sounds), you can always construct your own exponentiation template using e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring. This is assuming you cannot use XSLT 2.0 or higher, where exponentiation is supported natively.

Comment: I don't think calculations belong in UI code.  Better to keep it on the server.

Comment: Server? UI? Do you even XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. There is no `math:power()` function in standard XPath.

   - If you're using XPath 2.0 or greater, bind the `math:` namespace   prefix to its standard `"http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"`
     value an use the [`math:pow()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-math-pow) function which *returns the result of raising the first argument to the power of the second*.
   - If you're using XPath 1.0, you can use the EXSLT extension library<sup>1</sup> (with `math:`bound to `"http://exslt.org/math"`).  However, note that at least [one implementation of EXSLT `math:power()`](https://exslt.github.io/math/functions/power/math.power.function.xsl) does not support negative powers:

     ```
     <xsl:when test="$power < 0 or contains(string($power), '.')">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes"> The XSLT implementation of 
           math:power() doesn't support negative or fractional 
           arguments. </xsl:message>
        <func:result select="number('NaN')"/>
     </xsl:when>
     ```
2. The expression, `7`<sup>`-2`</sup>, does not equal `0.07`.  It equals `1/(7`<sup>`2`</sup>`)` = `1/49`, which equals approximately `0.02040816326`.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to [@michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k) for the suggestion regarding possible EXSLT extension failure.</sub>

Comment: The error message refers to an extension function, so clearly this is not `pow()` but rather EXSLT `math:power()` or similar.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I think you're right.  Answer clarified.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> The expression works with a positive power but it does not work with a negative power.

Well, then the easiest solution would be to change the expression from:

```
<xsl:value-of select="math:power($base, $exponent)"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$exponent &lt; 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="math:power(1 div $base, -$exponent)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="math:power($base, $exponent)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want 7 times 10 to the power of -2, that is 0.07, then the way to achieve this is `7 * math:pow(10, -2)`.

I'm assuming here that the prefix `math` is bound to `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math`.

But perhaps it is instead bound to `http://exslt.org/math`. This namespace does have a function named `math:power()` which is described at `https://exslt.github.io/math/functions/power/index.html`. The specification is rather brief and informal and there are no examples, so it's entirely possible that some implementation doesn't support negative exponents. Older releases of Saxon did implement the EXSLT math function library, but it was withdrawn some while ago in favour of the W3C version.